# Is it possible to submit a form from a page to another page that has an iframe?

Tags: iframe, submit

Is it possible to submit a form from a page to another page that has an iframe ? The page with iframe inside already has a submit form that submits to iframe.

So, I need page A to submit to page B which submits to iframe within.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can do one of two things:

1. The one that makes the most sense is to submit directly to the URL of the iframe within Page B
2. You can also include the iframe on page A, and place a target attribute on the form itself to submit to the iframe.

The way you have it set up, with the man in the middle, won't work. Most browsers won't let you automatically submit a form without some sort of user interaction, like a mouse click or keyboard event.

Comment: To clarify the reason behind all this, I have a job site which has a very nice home page (A). When people complete the search form and push submit on home page(A), I need to load another page (B) which has nice search form header and iframe inside which shows results. ( iFrame its the php script engine which shows the search results. I cannot redesign that part). Because I can't use page B as homepage, when people complete form on page A and push search, will load page B, which will come with results, if possible..

Comment: Maybe by completely hide the iFrame within the page A and load it with results only when submit button is pushed, can this be possible ?